# The program cannot connect to database after closing netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, jdbc, derby

I am currently developing an application in Java by Using Netbeans 8.0.2.

Previously, I used MySql as DBMS but then I learn that I cannot put this database into my .jar file because of that, I switched to Derby.

When I execute the program while Netbeans is on even if the DB is disconnected, everything works perfect but as soon as I close the Netbeans, I tried to run my application from .Jar, it gives following error..

```
java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: java.net.ConnectException
```

and my code looks like;

```
Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver");
Connection con = 
    DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/emir;create=true", "root", "root");

Statement st = con.createStatement();
```

as the driver, I am using derbyclient.jar

I looked up other similar problems and questions but they did not help me.
Thank you guys in advance,

Comment: Hi ,Are you testing if   engine DB service continuous running, after close netbean ?

Comment: @santiago92 After completing my project, I will hand in my project as jar file and when it does not connect to DB, it is of course useless.. Now, as I described, when the netbeans is open, my program works perfect in netbeans and comandline as well but after closing netbeans, it does not connect to DB from commandline.

Comment: Your issue is that starting and stopping NetBeans is also starting and stopping the Derby Network Server, so when NetBeans is down, so is the Derby Network Server. Derby has several possible configurations. To  better understand the difference between Network Server and Embedded modes, start here: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.11/getstart/cgstutorialintro.html

Comment: @BryanPendleton Thank you for the link.. In order to make my program run, should I setup Derby Network Server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem with the help of following link. I suggest all beginners for derby-java to read this.

http://zetcode.com/db/apachederbytutorial/netbeans/